# Form Submission Using Ajax not working

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem getting my form to insert the records into the database. I just can't figure out where I'm wrong...

My form is bellow

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<form id="form" name="form">
    <div>
        <label>Name :</label>
        <input id="name" type="text">
        <label>Email :</label>
        <input id="submit" onclick="myFunction()" type="button" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

a script script.js

```
function myFunction() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var dataString = 'name1=' + name;
    if (name == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxjs.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

and a php script ajaxjs.php

```
<?php
include ('./includes/connection.php');
$name1 = $_POST['name1'];
if (isset($_POST['name1'])) {
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO db VALUES('TEST','name1')");
}
?>
```

developer tools show message:
script.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: dataString is not definedmyFunction @ script.js:5onclick @ test.html:9

Comment: Turn on developer tools in your browser and see the error your getting update your question with the error

Comment: @Danturnip script.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: dataString is not definedmyFunction @ script.js:5onclick @ test.html:9

Comment: Sidenote: even if it works without errors, you'd be inserting a constant string (`name1`) instead of the posted value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ajax code working well
But your query command look like wrong
Please try

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

[image]

Update: Source code working well

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var dataString = 'name1=' + name;
        if (name == '') {
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxjs.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
<form id="form" name="form">
<div>
<label>Name :</label>
<input id="name" type="text">
<label>Email :</label>
<input id="submit" onclick="myFunction()" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

And ajaxjs.php

```
<?php
    // include ('./includes/connection.php');
    $name1 = $_POST['name1'];
    echo $name1;
    // if (isset($_POST['name1'])) {
    // $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO db VALUES('TEST','name1')");
    // }
?>
```

Comment: You can omit the column names if you provide a value for each table column. [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html): _If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES [..], values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES [...]_

Comment: I think his query not working and I give one example.

Comment: Yes bro, I know it. xD I just give one full example xD

Comment: @Menel Hardly... I did nothing xD

Comment: Ah soz, I mean Quynh

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Thanks for solving my problem. Worked.